# SQL Boolean Logic Conditions

Tags: sql, boolean-logic

I am confused on this statement and why it is true.

**If type is 'rare', then price must be over $500**

This condition meets it, but I am confused how.

```
CHECK (type <> 'rare' OR price > 500)
```

This question as well,
**If type is 'novel', then price must be over $10 but less than $30.**

```
CHECK ((type <> 'novel') OR (price > 10 AND price < 30))
```

Comment: form `CHECK (type <> 'rare' OR price > 500)`, use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be hard to grasp conceptually why these are equivalent.  It might help to start with the four conditions possible, relative to:  if type is `rare` then price must be over $500.

```
Type = 'rare', price > $500:   True
Type <> 'rare', price > $500:  True
Type = 'rare', price <= $500:  False
Type <> 'rare', price <= $500  True
```

You can go through the same exercise for (type <> 'rare' OR price > 500`, and you'll see that they are logically equivalent.

Why?  Intuitively, the expression: "if type is `rare` then price must be over $500" is only "cares" about type being rare.  If the type is *not* rare, then the statement is true.  Similarly, if the price is greater than $500, then it will always be true.  The `check` expression is just capturing these two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

"A or B" means at least one of these statements is true. If A is not true (type = 'rare'), then B must be true (price > 500) to satisfy the condition. Second statement you have has exactly the same logic.